# Connect 3+ OpenDaylight controllers to mininet topology

Tags: bundle, cluster-computing, mininet, opendaylight

I would like to ask
I have created a cluster according to this
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-magnesium/getting-started-guide/clustering.html

And i would like to verify it is working can someone help me how to do it?

Also is it able to connect this cluster or those 3 controllers to one mininet topology? Or it cant be done?

EDIT
I would like to ask why 
[Not all bundle are active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S88e.jpg)?
Is there gonna be some problem with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can specify multiple controllers on the mininet command
line, but it's worth a try. Otherwise you can try like this person explains
in this [post](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/14459/opendaylight-cluster-problem-in-mininet/) setting up the controllers in a mininet .py config file.

To verify the cluster is working, there are many ways, but you can try some
rest calls to check the status of things. We have some examples in upstream
CSIT tests. If you install the feature odl-jolokia, you can send a GET to:

```
jolokia/read/org.opendaylight.controller:Category=Shards,name=member-1-shard-default-config,type=DistributedConfigDatastore
```

that is checking the default shard status for the config datastore. You'll get
some output like this:

```
content={
 "request": {
  "mbean": "org.opendaylight.controller:Category=Shards,name=member-1-shard-default-config,type=DistributedConfigDatastore",
  "type": "read"
 },
 "status": 200,
 "timestamp": 1588524930,
 "value": {
  "AbortTransactionsCount": 0,
  "CommitIndex": 70,
  "CommittedTransactionsCount": 0,
  "CurrentTerm": 7,
  "FailedReadTransactionsCount": 0,
  "FailedTransactionsCount": 0,
  "FollowerInfo": [],
  "FollowerInitialSyncStatus": true,
  "InMemoryJournalDataSize": 33,
  "InMemoryJournalLogSize": 1,
  "LastApplied": 70,
  "LastCommittedTransactionTime": "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000",
  "LastIndex": 70,
  "LastLeadershipChangeTime": "2020-05-03 16:54:45.034",
  "LastLogIndex": 70,
  "LastLogTerm": 7,
  "LastTerm": 7,
  "Leader": "member-2-shard-default-config",
  "LeadershipChangeCount": 1,
  "PeerAddresses": "member-3-shard-default-config: akka.tcp://opendaylight-cluster-data@10.30.170.119:2550/user/shardmanager-config/member-3-shard-default-config, member-2-shard-default-config: akka.tcp://opendaylight-cluster-data@10.30.170.113:2550/user/shardmanager-config/member-2-shard-default-config",
  "PeerVotingStates": "member-3-shard-default-config: true, member-2-shard-default-config: true",
  "PendingTxCommitQueueSize": 0,
  "RaftState": "Follower",
  "ReadOnlyTransactionCount": 0,
  "ReadWriteTransactionCount": 0,
  "ReplicatedToAllIndex": 69,
  "ShardName": "member-1-shard-default-config",
  "SnapshotCaptureInitiated": false,
  "SnapshotIndex": 69,
  "SnapshotTerm": 7,
  "StatRetrievalError": null,
  "StatRetrievalTime": "557.3 \u03bcs",
  "TxCohortCacheSize": 0,
  "VotedFor": "member-2-shard-default-config",
  "Voting": true
 }
}
```

Lots of info there, but the raftstate says Follower, so you know this node
is one of the two followers. One node will be leader.

Another thing we check is syncstatus to make sure it's "true". Use this
URI:

```
    jolokia/read/org.opendaylight.controller:Category=ShardManager,name=shard-manager-operational,type=DistributedOperationalDatastore
```

[example output](https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/controller-csit-3node-clustering-ask-all-magnesium/235/robot-plugin/log.html.gz#s1-s12-t5-k2-k1-k8-k2-k2-k1-k1-k6-k2)

Comment: I have found something like this.
https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Cluster-Edition-Prototype?fbclid=IwAR3o6lHnokyBExHUjj6as15mioheAR7O5XDQNK3gQ8vLwyJz9ROMLOE11Y8#when
i am not sure if it is what i have been loking for or if it is gonna work but i ll try.

For veryfing I have installed the jolokia but this GET it is like i need POSTMAN or where do i put that command ? I am sorry if my question is dumb but.

Comment: I use 'curl' on the command line, but postman is nice to use as well. It's something to learn how to do if you are going to be interacting with something like OpenDaylight.

Comment: I have managed to do it both ways but for some reason i have recieved input like unauthorized and i dont know why

Comment: This is the result:
https://imgur.com/a/NE1xKxV
Could you please tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: I found out that i have to use parameters with pasword. Nevermind Thank you for your help.